# Unlock the Android Lockscreen activity

Tags: android

I have a running android Service. It runs even on the lockscreen,
and i want it to somehow Unlock the lockscreen.

How can i 'interfere' with the lockscreen activity or whatever the lockscreen is?

Update:

I want my service to Unlock the lockscreen, just like if the user slided the unlock thing.

Got it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. Use this code:

```
Window window = getWindow();  
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

This will unlock the Keyguard automatically.

Comment: This flag does not work on Android 2.2  I don't know why, but it doesn't unlock and remove the keyguard.

Comment: Well, I am 100 per cent sure this works on Froyo. Yes, it does NOT unlock the pin/password/pattern lock (for that you need the DEVICE ADMIN permission), but the normal slide.