# Phone Call initiates but disconnects?

Tags: android, phone-call

I am working on an Android application which initiates a call on phone remotely using a service.

The problem that occurs is, when I freshly install the application and initiate the call it works fine only for the first time and the call is initiated. But when I try to initiate the call second time or afterwards, then the call initiation screen appears but the call disconnects immediately. Can anyone suggest what can be the main reason behind? How can I sort out this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the logcat output. If nothing relevant is present then look at the commands sent to and received when creating the first call and how they are different the second time around.

Comment: i have the logcat files of both events, i cant see any major difference or may be i am not able to understand. can you help?

Comment: You should post your logcat for everyone to see.

Comment: i think i got the reason behind. i dont know wheather it is right or wrong, the call disconnects when the screen is locked and may be it is prevented that you initiate the call when screen is locked and that is why it gets disconnected. when i explicitly unlock the screen and then generate the call it works fine.

Comment: That would make sense. I believe that you can unlock the screen. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051010/unlock-the-android-lockscreen-activity.